# Name for progressions, Sz = an and Sz \= an

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was observing that in some progressions, it can happen that $ S_z = a_n $, where $ S_z$ represents the sum of z terms, and $ a_n $ the term of order $n$. For example in the progression $(1,2,3,4,5...)$ , i noticed that $S_2 = a_3$. Otherwise in the progression $ ( \pi, \pi + \sqrt{2}, \pi + 2\sqrt{2}...) $, $S_z \neq a_n$ for $z,n \neq 1$. Does this progressions receive a special name, in both cases for $S_z = a_n$ and $S_z \neq a_n$?

Comment: I don't know of any special name for the property you listed. Furthermore, I don't really think that the property is particularly interesting, so it makes no sense to name it...

Comment: I would avoid using the letter $z$ for anything other than complex numbers, here.. Aside from that, I haven't seen any name for this kind of sequence. Oh, it is interesting, come on..